# Insert Cells and Sections from Table Views

Tags: objective-c, cell, uitableview, sections

Help me ! I can not able to insert cells in section tableviews !

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
            NSInteger result = 0;
            result = [[_dictionoryOfDay allKeys] count];
            return result;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
       NSInteger result = 0;
        NSString *sectionNameInDictionary = [[_dictionoryOfDay allKeys]
                                         objectAtIndex:section];
        NSArray *sectionArray = [_dictionoryOfDay objectForKey:
                             sectionNameInDictionary];
        result = [sectionArray count];
        return result;
    }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        UICustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellMain" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell.btnAddMore addTarget:self action:@selector(actionAddMore:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.btnAddMore.tag = indexPath.section;
        return cell;
    }

    -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        TableHeaderAvailabel *header;
        if(!header){
              header = [tableView  dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"TableHeaderAvailabel"];
         }
         NSString *result = nil;
         result = [[self.dictionoryOfDay allKeys] objectAtIndex:section];
         header.lbTitle.text = result;
         return header;
    }

    -(void)actionAddMore:(UIButton *)sender{

    }
```

Comment: Can you please reformat your question so we can understand your code a little better?  Use the 'help' text to show you how to surround your code with the proper Markdown formatting.  Also, please indicate what you've tried to do to solve the problem.

Comment: so what is your problem? where is the code where you are inserting the rows/sections `actionAddMore` is empty?

Comment: image : http://i.stack.imgur.com/lJNTE.jpg

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you want to add a *row* to your section when you tap on a cell's `btnAddMore`. If that's the case, then the implementation of `actionAddMore()` should look like

```
    NSString *sectionNameInDictionary = [[_dictionoryOfDay allKeys]
                                     objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *sectionArray = [_dictionoryOfDay objectForKey:
                         sectionNameInDictionary];
    // Create whatever you use to populate rows
    [sectionArray addObject: <your new object>];
    _dictionaryOfDay[sectionNameInDictionary] = sectionArray;
    [self.tableView reloadData];    // Or just load the new cell, but this is easier
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Example : Insert cells to section Tuesday or Thursday.I have to do now ?
This is my picture 
http://postimg.org/image/ecmjk21or/